# Question about strange outputs from the CVXPY solver

Tags: optimization, python, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I am familiarizing myself with CVXPY, and encountered a strange problem. I have the following simple toy optimization problem:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

A=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
y=np.array([1,1,1])

# Upper bound for the constraint term
upper=1
# Solve the optimization problem using CVXPY
x = cp.Variable(3)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x))
constraint = [cp.sum_squares(A*x - y) <= upper]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)
prob.solve()
optimal_x = x.value

print('Value of constraint at optimal x:' + str(np.linalg.norm(A*optimal_x - y)**2))
```

Now, I expect my output number to be samller than `upper=1`, but what I get is the following:

```
Value of constraint at optimal x:3.0000000068183947
```

I am very confused about how this could be true. Am I using the function `cp.sum_squares` incorrectly? Am I just setting up the optimization in a wrong way? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I suspect that this will be flagged as off-topic, see https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, since it is "essentially about debugging a code sample, or about low-level language syntax". But anyway, one thing to check is whether `A*x` in cvxpy and `A*optimal_x` in NumPy mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a broadcast (`A*x`), rather than matrix multiplication (`A@x`), so your code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

A=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
y=np.array([1,1,1])

# Upper bound for the constraint term
upper=1
# Solve the optimization problem using CVXPY
x          = cp.Variable(3)
objective  = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x))
constraint = [cp.sum_squares(A@x - y) <= upper]
prob       = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)
prob.solve()
optimal_x = x.value

print('Value of constraint at optimal x: {0}'.format(np.linalg.norm(A@optimal_x - y)**2))
```

Which gives

```
Value of constraint at optimal x: 1.000000002699704
```